# Use database connection in excel formula - no VBA

Tags: excel, database

Some years ago, I used an excel file where I could retrive DB values with an in-cell formula, but I can't replicate this function.

My idea is to have a database connection (`access or sql`) with a connection to excel (`named "db1"`), in this there is a table ("`table1`") with some data about product and price (which are two colums).

My formula should be something like this:

```
=get_from_db(db1;"table1";"product"="car";"value")
```

Output should be the price of the product car.

Is it possible?

Thanks for your help

Simone

Comment: Did you do some research and already rule out some possibilities? From the title I conclude, you do not want to use VBA, for example. Are there other constraints?

Comment: Hi, actually no constraints, but I wanted an in-cell formula, without having to download the entire Table in excel